# SELECT DISTINCT CLASS FORM TABLE ORDER BY number of rows

Tags: sql, distinct

My table is

[image]

And I want result like this

```
class
------
Four  
Three  
Two  
One
```

Comment: Can you share what you've tried so far and is not working? Please keep in mind that this is not a teaching website where you post only the problem and expect a complete solution. The answer to this is not very hard if you know the basics of SQL. Kindly spend some time and visit the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and refer what to ask and how to ask.

Answer (score 4):

```sql
SELECT class
FROM your_table
GROUP BY class
ORDER BY count(*) desc
```

`GROUP BY` will group records by classes, effectively selecting distinct classes. Then you order by the per-class count.